# Jenkins SSH plugin - change the base directory for fileset (by default it is workspace. )

Tags: ssh, jenkins

I need to find a way to change the base directory for  fileset while using Jenkins SSH plugin -by default the base directory is workspace. 
IS there a way to do this

Comment: Which plugin are you using? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin or https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin or something else?

Comment: What is your end goal here? You can use a custom workspace, or like Simon said - remove the prefix if you're using publish over ssh, or change an SSH slave's remote working directory. More details required to answer your question properly...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin you can achieve this by using 'remove prefix' for any directory that is in your workspace.

If you want to transfer data that is outside your workspace you should probably describe what you are trying to achieve - there might be other solutions for that. The simplest solution will probably be to copy the files into your workspace using a build step.

Comment: @IJsfontein - The goal is to run automated build on a build server (Ec2 insatnce in Virgina region) and deploy to an app server (ec2 instance in APAC). My build script picks up code/artifacts from Jenkins workspace and other directories and then deploys to an interim (temp)directory on the same build server.  I need to copy the final code/artifacts from this interim (temp) directory and publish it to another EC2 instance in APAC region.  If I copy this code/artifacts back to Jenkins workspace. The next build will be a clean build (Jenkins will try to clone the whole repository again).