# Move files over SSH with jenkins outside the workspace

Tags: ssh, jenkins, liferay

I am trying to make a job for a liferay plugin and make it build the war and then transfer it to a remote liferay portal via the [Publish over SSH](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) plugin.

The workspace for my job is in the SDK portlets directory. The problem is that the build script of the liferay SDK is creating the war on a directory outside the workspace on a higher level, so the relative path is ../dist
The directory structure looks like this

```
- SDK root
+ - ...
  - dist (the dir where the war is being created)
  - ...
  - portlets (the workspace of my job)
  - ...
```

So, when I give the relative path [../dist/portlet_name.war] to the "Source Files" Field of the SSH publisher it finds 0 files to transfer:

```
SSH: Connecting SFTP channel ...
SSH: Connected
SSH: cd [/opt/liferay-portal]
SSH: OK
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [server_name [liferay]] ...
SSH: Transferred 0 file(s)
```

I also tried to give the absolute path, but with no success.

Is there a way to get the file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I 've found a possible solution, but it doesn't seem very elegant.

In the "Advanced Project Options" I set as custom workspace as the liferay SDK root directory and then in the "Source Code Management" on the Subversion section I set the "Local module option" to "portlets/ModulePortletName". The old value was "ModulePortletName". With this trick I moved the workspace directory 1 level higher, so now I can "see" the dist directory with the SSH as wished.

But I am sure there is a better solution for this problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15842673/533317) for this case,

> The simplest solution will probably be to copy the files into your workspace using a build step.

So you need to add "Execute Shell" step before transfering file :

```
# current dir is your job's workspace
rm -fr your.file
cp ../../anotherJob/workspace/target/your.file
```

Comment: a symbolic link is enough...
ln -s ../../anotherJob/workspace/target/your.file your.file